# HTML link to S3 videos, images

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have all my videos and images on S3, I want to use it instead of saving everything locally. I have successfully uploaded each image, however if I want to link the image in  tags, or even view it in browser I get:

public/images/facebook.png

instead of the actual image, here is the link used which is taken from S3 bucket:

Link: https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/liveandnow-development/public/images/facebook.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this:

```
<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
  <Message>The specified key does not exist. </Message>
  <Key>public/images/facebook.png</Key>
  <RequestId>...</RequestId>
  <HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>
```

This is an error that indicates that there is no object at `public/images/facebook.png`.

In fact, there are only 2 objects in this bucket.  How do I know this?  Your bucket security settings are incorrectly allowing anyone to list your objects.  You should fix this promptly.